# Nginx configuration permissions and ownership

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, nginx

My Nginx.conf uses www-data as the user. For individual Nginx configuration files (/etc/nginx/conf.d/) how should I have my permissions and ownership set.

```
root & 744 ?
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37894060/nginx-conf-and-nginx-pid-users-and-permissions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The permissions should not matter to Nginx as long as the daemon can read it, so `root:` and `744` are probably ideal.

As a note, generally all files in `/etc/` should be owned as `root:root` and generally `744` unless security-critical to prevent dangerous tampering by users or exploited services (where the permissions should be even more restrictive like `root:root` `600`).